# How can I get a Material SplitView in an ajax page? - Framework7

Tags: ajax, html-framework-7

So I'm trying to make it so you go to a settings page from the main page kind of like the Settings tablet app on Android or iOS where it's a split view (Example of what happens down below). However I'm constantly running into trouble where I can't seem to get it to work. It always looks like it's on a single page. I tried using views in JavaScript, I tried rearranging HTML, I tried many combinations just to get it to work, however I can never get it to work. If you need anything else to get a broader picture, let me know.

Here's the page hierarchy:
Root dashboard page > Settings Button > Settings SplitView

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have tried to add left-view and right-view class with the data-view attribute ?

for more information read the [views doc](http://framework7.io/docs/linking-views.html) and have a look to the  [split-view example](http://framework7.io/examples/split-view/)